# $2$ basic questions in combinatorics with conditions such as seating members around a table, one members has to be between two others and such.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> First question, $n$ families , each family has a father, mother, child and a dog, sit around a circular table.
> in how many ways can they be seated :
>
> 1. no conditions
> 2. every child sits between the parents
> 3. every couple sits together, and no dogs are next to each other.
>
> Second question, in how many ways can we place $4$ objects with different weights in $7$ drawers that are sorted one above the other (they are distinguishable) in the following conditions:
>
> 1. no conditions
> 2. the lightest and heaviest objects are not together
> 3. the highest drawer has exactly one object and the lowest drawer has at least 1 object
> 4. each drawer has at most one object

---

First question:

for the first part we have $n$ families , $1$ circular table and each family has $4$ members , so we have in total $4n$ seats and according to circular permutation formula it will be $\frac{(4n)!}{4n}$

the second part we first seat one of the parents (doesn't matter who) in a certain place around the table and then we seat the child we have 2 ways to seat the parents 2 ways to seat the child and 2 ways to seat the dog so $2\cdot2\cdot2=8$ and we need to do this for $n$ families so $8^n$

I did not understand the last part does that mean the parents are considered now $1$ instead of $2$ or does it mean that they sit next to each other?

Second question:

first part: $P(7,4)=7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 840$ sorting 4 different objects in 7 different drawers

second part:  assume the objects are $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with the lightest being $a$ and heaviest $b$
first lets put $\{a,b,c\}$ in the 7 drawers  $P(7,3)=7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 =210$
same thing for $\{b,c,d\}$ but $a$ must be in one drawer so $P(6,3)=6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 =80$ lastly we sum the options and get $210+80=290$

third part: let $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$ be the drawers while $A$ is the one on the bottom and $G$ being the highest we will put one object in $G$ , we have $4$ ways of doing that so we are left with $3$ objects and $6$ drawers while the bottom one has at least $1$ object so we have 3 cases

1. $3 \choose 1$ $\cdot P(5,2)=60$
2. $3 \choose 2$ $\cdot P(5,1)=15$
3. $3 \choose 3$ $\cdot P(5,0)=1$

summing up all the options we get $4+60+15+1=80$

fourth part: the first object has $7$ options the second has $6$ third has $5$ and fourth has $4$ so we get $7+6+5+4=22$

are my ways correct? these are the only questions in the book without answers.. thanks for any tips and help hopefully my translations are understandable

Comment: I would assume that "every couple sits together" means that husband and wife are always seated next to each other.  Of course, they could be seated in either order.

Comment: Note:  I don't understand your solution to the first (unconstrained) problem.  If, say, we regard the dog in family $1$ to be seated at the head of the table, then there are $3+4(n-1)$ other "people" to be seated who can go in any order...no idea where $6^n$ comes from

Comment: @lulu I thought that since we have $3!$ ways to seat each family and we have $n$ families then it is like $3! \cdot 3!...\cdot 3!$ $n$ times so it will be $3!^n$

Comment: Why do you have $3!$ ways to seat each family?  Aren't there $4!$ (other than the family with the special member, I mean)?  Also, who said the families were seated together?  I figured "no conditions" meant "no conditions". Anyway, if the families were seated in blocks, you'd still have to order the families.

Comment: @lulu $3!$ because its a circular table , from what I know if you sort people in a line it is $n!$ and if it is a circle then $(n-1)!$ by no conditions it just means to seat them around the table with no conditions on for example who wants to be next to the the other , Sorry if the translations are not clear I will try to edit

Comment: You aren't seating them each at a separate circular table!  Or, if you are, you really need to rewrite your post.  I thought there was one huge table, with $4n$ seats.  And by putting dog $\#1$ at the head of the table, I have handled the rotations.

Comment: @lulu I rechecked the questions it seems like it is just one huge table , I did not even think about $4n$ seats guess my solving is just wrong here

Comment: @lulu is the first part correct now ?

Comment: Yes. After the head is set, there are $(3+4n-4)= 4n-1$ "people" to be seated with no conditions, so $(4n-1)!$

Comment: Note: I initially misread your answer and have edited my prior comment accordingly.

Comment: Are you saying all $n$ of the dogs are next to each other?  Or just that each dog sits adjacent to at least one other dog?

Comment: @RobertShore I just edited , I meant no dogs next to eachother sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

Part $1$:  There are $4n$ distinguishable "sitters."  Assuming that two arrangements are the same if they differ only by a rotation, since there are $4n$ possible rotations for each permutation, there are $\dfrac{(4n)!}{4n}=(4n-1)!$ possible arrangements.  Your answer is correct but can be expressed more simply.

Part $2$:  If every child sits between the parents, then consider parent-child-parent as a single unit.  There are, therefore, $2n$ units to arrange, which can be done in $(2n)!$ ways.  However, each parent-child-parent unit can be formed in $2$ different ways, so there are $2^n \cdot (2n)!$ possible permutations.  Again we must divide by $4n$ to account for rotations, so there are $2^{n-1} \cdot (2n-1)!$ possible arrangements.  Your answer is not correct because the problem doesn't require a family's dog to be adjacent to the family.

Part $3$:  If every couple sits together and none of the dogs sit next to each other, first arrange the couples and the children.  There are $2n$ units to arrange ($n$ pairs of parents and $n$ children), which can be done in $(2n)!$ ways.  There are $2^n$ ways to arrange the parents within each pair.

There are $2n$ "gaps" into which we can place the dogs.  The first dog can choose any of the $2n$ gaps.  The second dog has $2n-1$ gaps to choose from, and so on.  We can therefore place the dogs in $\dfrac {(2n)!}{n!}$ ways.  Another way to see this is that there are $\binom {2n}{n}$ ways to choose the gaps the dogs will fill, and once that's done there are $n!$ ways to arrange the dogs within those gaps, so there are $n! \cdot \binom{2n}{n}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}$ ways to place the dogs.

Thus, there are $2^n \cdot (2n)! \dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}$ possible permutations.  Once again we need to divide by $4n$ to account for rotations, yielding $2^{n-1} \cdot (2n-1)! \dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}$ possible arrangements.

Second question:

Part $1$:  If any object can go into any drawer, then each of the $4$ objects has $7$ possible locations, so there are $7^4=2401$ possible arrangements.  Your answer is incorrect because it's possible for a drawer to contain more than $1$ object.

Part $2$:  If the lightest and heaviest object must go into different drawers, then (going in ascending order by weight) there are $7$ choices for each of the first $3$ objects, but only $6$ choices for the $4$th object, so there are $6 \cdot 7^3=2058$ possible arrangements.  Your answer is incorrect because you "inherited" the mistake you made in Part $1$.

Part $3$:  If the highest drawer has exactly $1$ object, there are $4$ choices for what that object can be.  There are $6^3=216$ ways to arrange the other $3$ objects among the remaining $6$ drawers without constraint.  However, in $5^3=125$ of those arrangements, the lowest drawer has no object.  Therefore, there are $4 \cdot (216-125)=364$ permissible arrangements.  I'm not sure how you got the various figures you're combining but your answer is not correct.

Part $4$:  If each drawer has at most one object, then there are $7$ choices for the first object, $6$ choices for the second object, $5$ choices for the third object, and $4$ choices for the fourth object, for a total of $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4=840$ possible arrangements.  Your answer is not correct because you added when you needed to multiply.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanations, in the first question part 3 , my mistake it is supposed to be "no dogs are next to eachother"

Comment: Everything is understandable and I appreciate the help just one question as I was going through it all again , why $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ ways for the dogs? I do not understand the $n!$? is it because there are $n$ dogs? why not divide by $2n$ ?

Comment: @Adamrk I've edited to provide another way to see why that's the correct answer.